# tohavebeencalled - expected a spy, but got a function

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

This is the test:

```
it("clock should get test from testService", () => {
    let testString = `test`;
    expect(this.langService.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith(testString);
}
```

This was working before when providers looked like this:

```
providers: [
    companyTestUtil.getMockLangServiceProvider()
]
```

Now providers looks like this:

```
providers: [
    ...companyTestUtil.getMockBackendDeps(),
    companyTestUtil.getTestLangServiceProvider(testLangServiceConfig),
    mockSingerServiceProvider
]
```

...and I get started getting error:

> Error:  : Expected a spy, but got Function.
>       Usage: expect().toHaveBeenCalledWith(...arguments)

I printed out `this.langService.get` when correct, it looked like `LOG: function () { ... }`

But when there's error, it started looking like this: `LOG: function(key,count,params){ ... }`

Comment: Can you show your whole test?

Answer (score 0):

Methods like toHaveBeenCalledWith can only be used on mocked functions, so in your case you can put a spy on get method of langService, if you modify your test case like this it will work:-

```
    it("clock should get test from testService", () => {
    spyOn(this.langService, 'get');
    let testString = `test`;
    expect(this.langService.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith(testString);
    }
```

Assuming get is a method and not a property accessor.

Comment: `Expected spy get to have been called with [ 'test' ] but it was never called` is what I get.

Comment: can you please share the method for which you're writing this test?

Answer (score 0):

You should spyOn languageService.get method.

```
it("clock should get test from testService", () => {
    spyOn(this.langService, 'get');
    let testString = `test`;
    expect(this.langService.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith(testString);
    }
```

Comment: `Expected spy get to have been called with [ 'test' ] but it was never called` is what I get.

Comment: You are not calling the method in your test . You should call the method otherwise it cant track the calls to function